# column names to column, pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

What is an apposite function of `pivot` in Pandas?

For example I have

```
a b c
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 1 2
```

What I want

```
a newcol newcol2
1  b      1
1  c      2
2  b      2
2  c      3
3  b      1
3  c      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use pd.melt  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[1,2,1],'c':[2,3,2]})

pd.melt(df,id_vars=['a'])

Out[8]: 
   a variable  value
0  1        b      1
1  2        b      2
2  3        b      1
3  1        c      2
4  2        c      3
5  3        c      2
```